# How to optimise the numerical evaluation of a SymPy integral?

Tags: python, optimization, sympy, symbolic-math, mpmath

I'm somewhat of a newbie to SymPy and was hoping someone could point out ways to optimise my code.

I need to numerically evaluate a somewhat involved expression with very high decimal places (150–300), and it is taking 30 seconds or longer per parameter set – which is very long given the parameter space to be calculated.

I have used `lambdify` with the `mpmath` backend and `meijerg=True` in the integral handling and it brought down run-times significantly. Are there any other methods that could be used? Ideally it would be great to push evaluation times below 1 second. My code is:

```
import mpmath
from mpmath import mpf, mp
mp.dps = 150 # ideally would like to have this set to 300 
import numpy as np
from sympy import besselj, symbols, hankel2, legendre, sin, cos, tan, summation, I
from sympy import  lambdify, expand, Integral
import time
x, alpha, k, m,n, r1, R, theta = symbols('x alpha k m n r1 R theta')

r1 = (R*cos(alpha))/cos(theta) #

Imn_part1 = (n*hankel2(n-1,k*r1)-(n+1)*hankel2(n+1,k*r1))*legendre(n, cos(theta))*cos(theta)
Imn_part2 = n*(n+1)*hankel2(n, k*r1)*(legendre(n-1, cos(theta)-legendre(n+1, cos(theta))))/k*r1
Imn_parts = expand(Imn_part1+Imn_part2)
Imn_expr = expand(Imn_parts*legendre(m,cos(theta))*(r1**2/R**2)*tan(theta))
Imn = Integral(Imn_expr, (theta, 0, alpha)).doit(meijerg=True)

# the lambdified expression
Imn_lambdify = lambdify([m,n,k,R,alpha], Imn,'mpmath')
```

When giving numerical inputs to the function – it takes a long time (30 s – 40 s).

```
substitute_dict = {'alpha':mpf(np.radians(10)), 'k':5,'R':mpf(0.1), 'm':20,'n':10}

print('starting calculation...')
start = time.time()
output = Imn_lambdify(substitute_dict['m'],
             substitute_dict['n'],
             substitute_dict['k'],
             substitute_dict['R'],
            substitute_dict['alpha'])
print(time.time()-start)
```

OS/package versions used:

- Linux Mint 19.2
- Python 3.8.5
- SymPy 1.7.1
- MPMath 1.2.1

Comment: Why do you need that many digits? This kind of accuracy is hardly ever needed. The only thing I can imagine is if you are facing something like extreme [cancellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catastrophic_cancellation) within the expression.

Comment: Hi @Wrzlprmft thanks for the ping! I'm trying to porting some Mathematica code, and the original author recommended such high precisions. Does extreme cancellation cause longer compute times - any ideas on how to work around this problem?

Comment: I am not saying that cancellation happens, just that it would be about the only reason I can imagine to go for such high accuracies. Cancellation can cause massive inaccuracies when not properly handled. These may occasionally lead to longer computing times, but that would be the least of your problems.

Comment: Two insights: 1) `Imn` still includes abstract integrals, which means that `doit` will evaluate them numerically. The inaccuracy of this is almost certainly higher than your 150 digits. 2) When you remove MPMath (except as an argument for `lambdify` since it seems to be able to handle the complex values as desired), everything runs in a second and yields the same result (for many digits). — From this I would guess that there is no reason to work with high-precision. For speeding it up further, your best way is probably to work with a vectorised integrand.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft doit() evaluates the integral symbolically, not numerically. There is no accuracy lost by doing so (although this particular integral cannot actually be computed in closed form by SymPy, so calling doit() is not actually very useful).

Comment: @asmeurer: My mistake. I noticed that the integral was evaluated numerically somewhere down the road and wrongly concluded that it would be during `doit`. Still, the point that the integral is evaluated numerically holds (right?) with all the inaccuracies that implies.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Evaluation with 150 digits will be accurate to all 150 digits. The only thing here that hampers that is the np.radians issue I noted in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Setting `meijerg=True` has just caused SymPy to not try as hard in evaluating the integral. It still can't evaluate it, but it has split it into 5 sub-integrals, which you can see if you print `Imn`. You might as well just leave it as one integral (leave off the `doit()`):

```
Imn = Integral(Imn_expr, (theta, 0, alpha))
```

For me, the split integral evaluates a little faster, but this is also about the same speed

```
Imn = Integral(simplify(Imn_expr), (theta, 0, alpha))
```

Ultimately, the thing that makes things slow is the number of digits that you are using. If you don't actually need these many digits, you shouldn't use them. Note that mpmath will automatically increase the precision internally to avoid cancellation, so it is unnecessary to do so yourself. I get the same value (with fewer digits) with the default dps of 15 as 150.

You can try substituting your values directly into your expression, if they do not change, and seeing if SymPy can simplify Imn_expr further with them.

As an aside, you are using `np.radians(10)`, which a machine float, since that is what NumPy uses. This completely defeats the purpose of computing the final answer to 150 digits, since this input parameter is only accurate to 15. Consider using `mpmath.pi/18` instead to get a value that is correct to the number of digits you specified.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply @asmeurer, learnt a lot! The split/simplified integral did indeed evaluate faster, and cut the time by 25% - which is pretty good. I'm also somewhat happy to hear that the ```dps``` is the main factor causing the delays. Keeping the 'default' ```dps``` doesn't recreate the results from the original code I'm trying to port. The ```Imn``` type terms feed into a matrix, and there's an ```mpmath.lu_solve``` operation, which tends to have errors that are 6 dps more than the set ```dps```. Perhaps this is where 'more' error creeps in?

Comment: Somewhat a separate though related question, was wondering if any of you had ideas on what kind of computer could do the job faster (high RAM/processor type) - given this is the fastest the code may reach, would it help to use something with more muscle - or is this already the limit?